# Run a forced DPF regeneration using OBD-II diagnostics

Tags: obd-ii, jeep, grand-cherokee, elm-327, diesel-particulate-filter

Our Jeep Grand Cherokee 2015 has problems with its exhaust filter. The error says we should drive safely at highway speeds to remedy but even after driving a few hours, it does not recover. It is stuck at 3rd gear (I believe this is called limp mode). Previously we had the same problem and a mechanic fixed it with an OBD-II dongle and some expensive software.

This time we bought a Wi-Fi ELM327 OBD-II dongle and connected with some free software. The error code was P2463. Last time the mechanic solved our problem with forcing the DPF regeneration. Is there a way we can do this on our own? I can't find any working solution on the internet.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: There is likely not a make/model specific code or command in a generic OBDII device to do this.  Your mechanic likely has a more sophisticated and expensive unit that has much more functionality.

Comment: Have you just tried to clear the code using your ELM327 device (and whatever app you're using)?